# How to blend multiple pre-made swatch gradients into 1 shape in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, gradient, swatches

[image]
I'm trying to make these separate rectangles into 1 rectangle with each gradient flowing seamlessly into one another.
Right now, the edges are too harsh for me and I want more smoothness.
All of these gradients are from the Metal swatches in the Gradient Library.

I tried using the **Blend** tool, but I was unsuccessful no matter which option I chose.

I made a gradient by hand to show you what I'm trying to do. 
Here are some examples.

[image]

My predicament is my hand made gradient takes a while. I write each swatch's RGB number down then one by one I add it to my new shape.

Is there any way of making this process easier? Am I missing something? I'm new to using these programs and this is the second time I'm coming across this problem. Doing it by hand gives the best results but I feel like I'm making the process more complicated than it needs to be.

Thanks in advance Adobe Veterans!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a single multi-colored gradient. I would *not* use blends here for any reason.

Set up the general swatches needed for each gradient.

Draw a rectangle and apply a gradient fill, then drag the swatches to the gradient to create the single multi-step gradient.

[image]

Once you have all the gradient stops, you can move them to position them as you'd like.

Comment: It should be noted that this will never be perfect unless you add more colors to the gradient.

Comment: Well you may need to play with some additional stops.. not sure you need *more colors* but you would need a few more color stops to be a bit smoother with it.

Comment: Sidebar: I really love how `<sarcasm>`GREAT!`</sarcasm>` Adobe's UI in the CC versions has become -- Like [**HERE!**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiKrz.jpg)

Comment: I think they pretty much only develop for people who use the darker UI's

Comment: Can't stand them dark UIs :)

Comment: @Scott i find it suprising that adobe does not understand that consistency with the rest of the OS is important. Oh dang it Adobe thinks it IS the OS. Anyway personally i would like to close the top icon area in swatches as it uses up space for no gain. I have color window open anyway. i dont need yet one more widget forwhat color is in fill and stroke.